# checking if cell empty or not

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I need to know how to do the following:

If coulmn A is not empty then column B or Column c in the same row should not be empty. I have this code

```
With Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    If Range("B1:B50").Value = "" Range("C1:50").Value = ""Or Then
        MsgBox "B or C must have a value"
    End If
End With
```

Right now it only works if Range B1.B50 is filled in all the way.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. You could just do a COUNTA function on the range in B and C based on the range in A. If they are the same then you have the same number of entries in each. What your code doesn't look into is if the cells next to the cells in Column A have a value. I think that would be more beneficial, you can then output in a message exactly which cells need to have a value.

Comment: Are you looking specifically for VBA solution? This can also be done with formulas.

Answer (score 0):

```
LastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows,SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
Range("A1").Select
Do Until ActiveCell.Row = LastRow + 1
 If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) = False Then
  If IsEmpty(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2)) = True Or IsEmpty(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3)) = True Then
   MsgBox "Row " & ActiveCell.Row & " has no value in Column B or C"
  End If
 End If
 ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
```

This could work. It's getting the last cell with an entry and then loops through each row, checking wether there is a Value in B or C, when A is not empty

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly! Can I do If IsEmpty(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2)) = True Then IsEmpty(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3)) = False?

Comment: @jojou96 What would you like to get/attain with this formula? as far as i know `isempty()` you can only read not set to true or false

Answer (score 0):

The code below will marked the cells with the value "!Err", suggest this instead of a long message, as the user will be able to see directly in the worksheet the cells in error.

```
Const kErr As String = "!Err"
Dim lRowCnt As Long
Dim lRow As Long
Dim bCellEmpty
Dim b As Byte

bCellEmpty = False
lRowCnt = Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
With Sheets(1)
    For lRow = 1 To lRowCnt
        If .Cells(lRow, 1).Value <> Empty Then
            For b = 2 To 3
                With .Cells(lRow, b)
                    If .Value = Empty Then
                        .Value = kErr
                        bCellEmpty = True
End If: End With: Next: End If: Next: End With
If bCellEmpty Then MsgBox "Cells marked with: """ & kErr & """ C must have a value"
```